# Sum all rows for each column within a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I am having difficulty with summing data across many rows for each datetimeindex. An example of the data frame is pasted below (although NOTE that i have over 40,000 rows to sum so It isn't as easy as df['total'] = df[0] + df[1]).

```
               0     1 
DateTime                          
2013-06-01 ,  0.05 , 0.24 

2013-06-02 ,  NaN , 0.48  

2013-06-03 ,  NaN , 0.48    

2013-06-04  , NaN , 0.48  

2013-06-05  , NaN , 0.48
```

The code that I use to sum this data is pasted below. I thought this should work however I have the below data frame returned which incorrectly sums the floats.

```
df['DailyTotal'] = df.sum(axis = 1)

               0     1  DailyTotal
DateTime                          
2013-06-01 ,  0.05 , 0.24    ,   0.00

2013-06-02 ,  NaN , 0.48   ,     0.02

2013-06-03 ,  NaN , 0.48    ,    0.02

2013-06-04  , NaN , 0.48      ,  0.02

2013-06-05  , NaN , 0.48   ,     0.02
```

Does anyone have any idea where I went wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this?

Comment: Are those commas really there?